# Почему при определенном имени программы ее запуск существенно замедляется?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

С такой мистикой сталкиваюсь впервые. Программа - буквально пустышка. В прямом смысле - простая `HelloWorld` - это я к ней уже дошел по ходу экспериментов. Компилирую в Visual C++ 2015 уже тупо без ключиков совсем. Получаю `mm.exe`. Запускаю. Выполняется секунд 6. Выводит, что надо. Но теперь самое интересное - если я компилирую с другим именем, да **просто переименовываю** `mm.exe` в какое-нибудь `rr.exe` или `mmm.exe` :) - все нормально! Мгновенное выполнение...

Windows 7 x64. Никаких `mm` в пути (`path`) не замечено.

**Update**
Код **любой**, например, сейчас этот:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello!\n";
}
```

Что эта мистика может значить?

Comment: 1. Приведите код в вопросе. 2. Попробуйте отключить антивирус.

Comment: @insolor Отключение антивирусника не помогло. Код привел. Компилирую `cl mm.cpp`. Запускаю из-под Far или из explorer'а - неважно.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вынесено из комментариев:

@KoVadim: в виндовом реестре есть большая ветка, где для разных программ добавлены различные правила. Например, для некоторых старых игр можно использовать память уже после освобождения. И определяет оно по имени файла. Я так уже когда то намучился.

@Harry: И в самом деле нашел `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameUX`, и там Might and Magic... Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Там может быть проблема с конфликтующим процесса, который имеет то же имя и каталог выполнения.

См [ссылка](http://www.file.net/process/mm.exe.html)

Comment: Запущенный процесс mm.exe в системе вроде бы отсутствует.